# Images not appearing when converting HTML to PDF via Flow

Tags: html, pdf, power-automate

I have an image which loads fine in HTML when converting to PDF through Microsoft flow it comes up with the Red X. Please see code below.

```
<div>
<img src='https://***********************************.jpg' alt='signature' style='width:500px;height:600px;'> 
</div>
```

Any ideas of how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the full path on your server and put that as base. The src path should be ***.bmp if your vase goes all the way down to images( if you set "base" option).
Plz provide you full code.

Comment: Thanks for answering. However you should not put link only answer. Maybe try to provide a bit more context. Please go through this answer to understand why link only answer should be discouraged. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259

Comment: Thanks for provide the links. I don't know the rules. From now i will follow this...

Comment: if it helps you to understand, please accept the answer, so that new people will get help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `PDF` is not able to create a `http` request, like browsers, thats why browsers can access the image but not `PDF`.

What you can do, place your image locally and then try to access in `HTML` and then convert your `HTML` to `PDF`

Try this, might help you